# how to launch certificate installer intent from the application to access root keystore

Tags: android, certificate, wifi

I am trying to install the CA certificate from the application but no luck. I am using android SDK 2.3.3.

I have found some reference to launch the credential storage dialog from the application. Can someone share some cod

Comment: you cannot ask code and just down vote someone's answer just because you didnt get the code. @Nikolay is right. You should search for "android.credentials.INSTALL" intent in android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to install a CA certificates? In Android 2.x, certificates and keys stored in credential storage are only used by the VPN and WiFi. The API for this is not public, but you can start the certificate installer with the "android.credentials.INSTALL" intent action.